# How to make a soil map with zones in QGIS

Tags: qgis, soil, agriculture

I'm trying to develop something in QGIS:

[image]

Basically, I want to do that, based on a set of data points like this:

[image]

I want to do something like that but in QGIS. The data will be used, eventually, to make prescription maps for agriculture and maybe reports. (Which I'm doing now but with another program).

I've been trying the interpolation methods (it make a raster layer), which are good and scientifically correct, but if I want to make, a report for example, it doesn't look good.

Comment: I think you need some sort of interpolation algorithm

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't look good" ? Raster are basically image and image can definitively look good, There are probably some setting (in symbolizing your raster or when creating it) that you can tweak to get good result

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Yes, of course. Sorry for the short explanation:
With looking good I mean looking smoother. (I'm aware of the tool "smooth". But it doesn't give me the result I want). 
The tool "Contour polygon"that Beni mentioned helped a lot ( I used that one and then zonal statistical to make a mean value in each zone).

Comment: In this case, I suggest using zonal statistics on your initial points layer. Else your interpolating and then aggregating your interpolations. And if the answer solves your problem, please accept it.

Comment: If your raster isn't smooth enough you probably need to use a smaller cell size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

interpolate your target variable to a raster (e.g. by `qgis:idwinterpolation`)
[image]

Symbolize that raster with discrete steps (in german: symbology > einkanalpseudofarbe > interpolation: Diskret)
[image]

or make contour-polygons of that raster (e.g. by `gdal:contour_polygon`)
[image]